# Custom Tweet Button Not Sending Text

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, tweets

I am placing a Tweet button on my website but it doesn't seem to be picking up the text.

My code is;

```js
var url = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
var title = document.title;
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=Check%20Out%20-"+title+"&url="+url+"">tweet</a>
```

I want the Tweet to read;

> Check Out - [My Page Title] - [My Page URL]

When I click the button I'm redirected to `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=` and I can see a Tweet box that displays `Check Out -` but no other text?

I'm adding this code into a Joomla CMS if that makes any difference (I don't want to use third party plugins etc.).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you cannot access the js variables in your HTML markup.

This means taht the variables won't be found.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. Do you happen to know how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: You could use js to create an <a> and render it into your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
    var title = document.title;
    
    $('#customTweetButton').attr('href', "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=Check%20Out%20-%20" + title + "&url=" + url);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="customTweetButton" target="_blank">Tweet</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I would approach this is by injecting an `<a>` tag in a specific `<div>` inside my HTML using Javascript.

```js
var url = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
var title = document.title;

document.getElementById("tweetAction").innerHTML = `<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=Check%20Out%20-` + title + `&url=`+ url + `">tweet</a>`
```

```html
<div id="tweetAction"><div>
```

Try tweet link by opening it in a new tab.